# R aggregate variable but duplicate new values in original dataframe

Tags: r, aggregate

I am new to R, and I've run into what I imagine is a very simple problem:

I am currently trying to aggregate an **hourly** variable to **daily** averages. The trick is I want to keep these new daily averages in my original data frame. While I have been able use aggregate() or summaryBy() for a new daily aggregated data frame, I would like to simply repeat averaged values within my original data frame. Shown below is a head from my frame:

```html
-               x           y
50              4.650097    2017-3-12-16
51              6.499223    2017-3-12-17
52              8.741650    2017-3-12-18
53              8.358922    2017-3-12-19
54              8.650971    2017-3-12-20
55              6.928252    2017-3-12-21
```

What I want to do is aggregate x, which is an hourly measurement, into a single daily average, but include those repeated averages as new columns.

For example, lets say the average of x was '6.12' for the first 24 rows. I want '6.12' to repeat as a new column for 24 rows, instead of creating a new single value vector.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr);
df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(as.POSIXct(strptime(y, "%Y-%m-%d-%H")))) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(mean.x = mean(x))
## A tibble: 9 x 5
## Groups:   date [2]
#     X.     x y            date      mean.x
#  <int> <dbl> <fct>        <date>     <dbl>
#1    50  4.65 2017-3-12-16 2017-03-12  7.30
#2    51  6.50 2017-3-12-17 2017-03-12  7.30
#3    52  8.74 2017-3-12-18 2017-03-12  7.30
#4    53  8.36 2017-3-12-19 2017-03-12  7.30
#5    54  8.65 2017-3-12-20 2017-03-12  7.30
#6    55  6.93 2017-3-12-21 2017-03-12  7.30
#7   100  5.00 2017-4-23-16 2017-04-23  5.00
#8   101  6.00 2017-4-23-17 2017-04-23  5.00
#9   102  4.00 2017-4-23-18 2017-04-23  5.00
```

Explanation: Convert `y` to `POSIXct` format, extract `date` component, `group_by` `date`, and create new column with daily `mean`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "-               x           y
50              4.650097    2017-3-12-16
51              6.499223    2017-3-12-17
52              8.741650    2017-3-12-18
53              8.358922    2017-3-12-19
54              8.650971    2017-3-12-20
55              6.928252    2017-3-12-21
100             5.0         2017-4-23-16
101             6.0         2017-4-23-17
102             4.0         2017-4-23-18", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as you haven't provided a reproducible form of your data (check out `dput`), but this should at least point you in the right direction. Just replace `mydf` with whatever your dataframe is called.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
aggregated_df <- mydf %>% 
  separate(y, c("date", "hour"), sep = -3) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(daily_average = mean(x))
```